# swift 3 issue with CVarArg being passed multiple times

Tags: swift

I have below code in swift 3:

```
 class StringUtility {

  static func Localizer(tableName: String?) -> (_ key: String, _ params: CVarArg...) -> String {
    return { (key: String, params: CVarArg...) in

      let content = NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: tableName, comment: "")

      if params.isEmpty {
        return content
      }

      print(params) ->>>>>> this prints [[[Wells Fargo]]]
      return NSString.init((format: content, arguments: getVaList(params))) as String
    }
  }
}

func localizationHelper(tableName: String, key: String, params: CVarArg...) -> String {
  let t = StringResourceUtility.Localizer(tableName: tableName)
  print(params) - >>>>>>>>>> this prints [[Wells Fargo]]
  return t(key, params)
}
```

If you see the print statements in above two functions, [] are appended every time CVarArg is passed inside functions resulting in wrong localization string outputted.

1) CVarArg cannot be passed multiple times like in above code ?
2) how to fix this ?

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot pass a variable argument list to another function, you
have to pass a `CVaListPointer` instead. Also `withVaList` should
be used instead of `getVaList`:

```
class StringResourceUtility {

    static func Localizer(tableName: String?) -> (_ key: String, _ params: CVaListPointer) -> String {
        return { (key: String, params: CVaListPointer) in
            let content = NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: tableName, comment: "")
            return NSString(format: content, arguments: params) as String
        }
    }
}

func localizationHelper(tableName: String, key: String, params: CVarArg...) -> String {
    let t = StringResourceUtility.Localizer(tableName: tableName)
    return withVaList(params) { t(key, $0) } 
}
```

Example:

```
let s = localizationHelper(tableName: "table", key: "%@ %@", params: "Wells", "Fargo")
print(s) // Wells Fargo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of the Martin R's answer. For some reason, I found the accepted answer a bit hard to read.

```
//create an extension on String class for ease of use
extension String {
  /// use this helper function when CVarArg parameters have to be passed multiple times
  func localize(using parameters: CVaListPointer) -> String {
      let localizedString = NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
      return NSString(format: localizedString, arguments: parameters) as String
  }
}
```

Once you defined the extension above do this on the call site.

```
class MyClass {
  /// some function that also accepts CVarArgs
  func fetchLocalizedMessage(params: CVarArg...) -> String {
     return withVaList(params) { pointerToVarArgs -> String in
       "a_key_in_localizable_file".localize(using: pointerToVarArgs)
     }
  }
}
```

Hopefully, you find this answer a bit easier to digest. Cheers!