# Convert nested array in swift to single dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, nested

I have a structure like `[[[ ]]]` which I want to convert to `[]`.

E.g. `[ [ [ "Hi" ] ] ]`  into  `[ "Hi" ]`

How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: Your question is unclear after your edit. What is `[ [ [ params: CVarArg... ] ] ]`? What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this a follow-up on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42428504/1187415? If yes, then you should say so.

Comment: it is the same question. just wanted to make explicit that argument type is CVarArg. at the end i am trying to do this - 
      return NSString(format: content, arguments: getVaList(params)). But problem is my params is coming as  [[[ ]]] and i want to convert it to []

Comment: I have answered your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42428504/1187415, but that one has nothing to do with converting nested arrays, only with passing variable argument lists. – I have therefore reverted *this* question to the initial version.

Answer (score 6):

[`joined()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/2432330-joined) returns (a lazy view of) the elements of an collection, concatenated. This can be applied repeatedly for
deeper nested collections:

```
let arr = [ [ [ "A", "B" ], ["C"] ], [ [ "D", "E" ], ["F"] ] ]

let flattened = Array(arr.joined().joined())
print(flattened) // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

The outer `Array()` constructor builds an array from the sequence.
Apart from that, no intermediate arrays are created.

If you just want to iterate over the nested array then the joined
sequence is sufficient:

```
for elem in arr.joined().joined() {
    print(elem)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what flatMap() does:

```
let arr = [ [ [ "A", "B" ], ["C"] ], [ [ "D", "E" ], ["F"] ] ]

// each call reduces the array by one dimension

let flattened = arr.flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}

// returns ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2298686-reduce) with your array this way.

```
let array = [[["One","Two","Three"],["Four","Five"]],[["Six"]]]
let newArray = array.reduce([]) { $0 + $1.reduce([]){ $0 + $1 } }
print(newArray) //["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use join as

```
let numbers = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
let newArray = Array(numbers.joined().joined())
print(newArray)//[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```