# How to properly use VarArgs for localizing strings?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a String extension that helps me internationalise.

```
public extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }

    func localized(args:CVarArg...) -> String{
        return NSString.localizedStringWithFormat(self.localized as NSString, args) as String
    }
}
```

This way I can easily use "hello_world".localized anywhere in the app and it works nicely.

Now I want to have the same functionality, but also want to be able to pass arguments. However passing the 'CVarArg...' doesn't seem to work as I'd expect it to.

`"grant_gps_access".localized("MyApp")`

Expected result: *"Please grant MyApp GPS access"*

Actual result: *"Please grant (\n    MyApp\n) GPS access"*

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27914308/2303865

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot pass a variable argument list to another function, you 
have to pass a `CVaListPointer` instead (the Swift equivalent
of `va_list` in C):

```
public extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }

    func localized(args: CVarArg...) -> String {
        return withVaList(args) {
            NSString(format: self.localized, locale: Locale.current, arguments: $0) as String
        }
    }
}
```

Since `NSString.localizedStringWithFormat` has no variant taking a
`VAListPointer`, the equivalent `NSString(format:, locale:, arguments:)` 
with the current locale is used.

Even simpler (attribution goes to @OOPer): Use
`String.init(format:locale:arguments:)` which takes a 
`[CVarArg]` argument:

```
    func localized(args: CVarArg...) -> String {
        return String(format: self.localized, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
    }
```

Now

```
"grant_gps_access".localized(args: "MyApp")
```

should work as expected, assuming that the strings file contains
the entry

```
"grant_gps_access" =  "Please grant %@ GPS access";
```

Comment: You can call `String.init(format:locale:arguments:)` without using `withVaList`.

Comment: @OOPer: You are right, that is simpler because it takes a `[CVarArg]` argument, I missed that!

Comment: @MartinR I tried your above solution, however, I am having the problem mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428504/swift-3-issue-with-cvararg-being-passed-multiple-times Also passing the CVaListPointer to the arguments isn't being allowed I get a compiler error. Know a workaround this?

Comment: I just tried the "simpler" solution and was still getting the same output (i.e. "Please grant (\n MyApp\n) access"). @Martin R's initial solution is the only one working for me.