# Localise a String with an unknown number of arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I have push notifications sent to the device with keys that have a value returned from Localizable.strings. The number of arguments is variable, sometimes it just needs one, sometimes it requires a few.

Normally to localise a string I would use this:

```
String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(notification.localisedKey, comment: "a comment"), notification.localisedArguments)
```

However this only works if `notification.localisedArguments` is a single value. If it's an array, it crashes.

The workaround in iOS 10 is to use the following code:

```
NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: notification.localisedKey, arguments: notification.localisedArguments)
```

How can I make do an equivalent for iOS 9 and lower?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457503/how-to-properly-use-varargs-for-localizing-strings.

Comment: @MartinR That code solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
let localizedString = NSLocalizedString(notification.localisedKey, comment: "a comment")
let result = withVaList(notification.localisedArguments) {
    String.localizedStringWithFormat(localizedString, $0)
}
```

Comment: This gives the error "Argument type 'CVaListPointer' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'" for the $0

Comment: @Tometoyou Hmmm, try this instead https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539624-getvalist

Comment: Ah solved it using some code from the link in Martin R's comment on my original post